# static pointer, initialiser is not constant?

Tags: c, pointers

What I thought static pointer is like other static variables, ones initialised with an value it have same value till end, like that the same address will be held in the static pointer. But in this case the compiler is throwing error

```
//initialiser element is not constant      static int *a = &b[0];

#include <stdio.h>
int main(void) 
{
    int b[2];

    static int *a = &b[0];  // removing static the program works well.
    printf("%u",a);

    a = &b[1];
    printf("%u",a);

    return 0;
}
```

So what is the use of static pointer?

Comment: Is that supposed to be C or C++? They are different languages, pick **one**!

Comment: @Olaf: This question is interesting with C and C++ tags set: the answer is very different.

Comment: @Bathsheba: That's the reason it should have one language tag only! Otherwise it would be too broad. But it can be asked twice, once for each language.

Comment: If you search "initializer not constant" on SO, you might find that this question has been asked many times before. http://stackoverflow.com/search?q=%5Bc%5D+initializer+not+constant

Comment: @Olaf: I'm never too sure about that; particularly if the question has an implicit "difference between C and C++" edge to it. I wonder if an expert will confirm my second paragraph?

Comment: Also my issue is with pointers @Lundin and not the constant property. There are no obvious questions about static pointers anywhere, So kindly release the duplicate

Comment: @aswinmythili The `static` part is the same for any kind of variable. The problem is that variables of _static storage duration_ must have a constant expression as initializer. As for "ones initialised with an value it have same value till end", that's not what static variables do, you seem to confuse them with `const`.

Comment: Got it now @olaf, Const and static differences are OK, And i understood finally that static pointer variable should pointer to one of constant variable or static variable, and not automatic variables, which i tried in the above. So nice explanation . Correct me if i'm wrong.

Comment: @aswinmythili: A pointer is a first-class variable. So why should it behave differently?

Comment: @aswinmythili: Why that differentiation? A static (which is not just `static` _qualified_ variables, but any at file-scope) variable needs a _constant-expression_ initialiser **point**. And that's exactly what the error message tells!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You have two options. Add static to `int b[2]`, or remove it from `int *a`. 
The address of `b` isn't static. It's variable, because `b` is a variable with automatic storage.

Comment: What is static pointer then, is it only for static variables?

Comment: @aswinmythili: The error message is very clear. Any static variable, which includes global variables, need to have a constant expression as initialiser. It becomes clear why if you have understood what static vriables actually are.

Answer (score 4):

In C, your code doesn't make sense. `b` has *automatic storage duration* so conceptually will have a different address each time `main` is encountered. The `static` will be initialised only once, and on subsequent invocations of `main` it may well point to something invalid.

**But**, and this is the interesting bit, in C++ it *ought* to make sense since you are not allowed to call `main` yourself: the behaviour on your doing so is *undefined*. So the inference of this is that the compiler *ought* to know that the `static` is valid for the lifetime of `main`, and compile the code! Perhaps there is something in the C++ Standard that explicitly forbids this.

In C you are allowed to call `main` recursively (even implicitly recursively), so the compiler ought to emit an error.

Comment: What is static pointer then, is it only for static variables?, Consider that i don't call main recursively.

Comment: A pointer with `static` storage duration will be initialised once. In this context, it would only really make sense if it were pointing to a variable with `static` storage duration.

Comment: I disagree with the "ought to" part. It would be special treatment for an otherwise automatic variable. Also the initialisation of static variables is done _before_ `main` is called, the the address of any automatic variable is not know at compile-time.

Comment: In C++ the initialisation of `static` variables at function scope happens conceptually when program control first encounters them (although a compiler is allowed to re-order that so long as there are no side effects). Are the rules for C different?

Comment: @Bathsheba: 1) OP asks about static variables, not `static` qualified only. 2) IIRC the standard requires all static variables (which includes `static` qualified) to be initialised on entry to `main`. I wounder that is different in C++ actually, as that would change the semantics for C++ objects compared to C. IIRC, gcc generates a list of static initialisers which is run from the startup code. But then I'm not sure this is just for global variables. Anyway; the C standard is clear about requiring constant expressions as initialisers, which an auto var is not.

Answer (score 0):

There may be confusion about `static` vs `const`.

Const variables will keep the same value from the time they are initialized until they go out of scope, unless `const_cast<>` is used, though as @Bathsheba mentioned in comment, use of `const_cast<>` on a variable declared const is undefined.

Static means it will get initialized at the spot first reaches but then not go out of scope until the end of program execution.

Comment: This is about C, not C++.

Comment: That would be my bad, sorry. I thought this question was found by watching the C++ tag.  (Looks like the user had C++ then put C after)

Comment: Note that the behaviour on attempting to change a varaible that was originally defined as const using a const_cast is undefined.

Comment: Yes I do understand that, I suppose I should edit.